# "Invalid State" after Vimeo API delete

Tags: php, curl, vimeo, dropzone.js, vimeo-api

Hopefully someone can help.. I'm using jQuery dropzone.js to upload the video and I can upload videos fine, but I can't "complete" the process so the videos always remain in a processing/uploading state. I'm performing the correct procedures according to the Vimeo API docs. Here are some headers/responses if they help, I've replaced some values with xxxx:

Upload request headers:

```
PUT /upload?ticket_id=xxxx&video_file_id=514311645&signature=acd2a6c4ba8c147651604793b081e053&v6=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 1511923755.cloud.vimeo.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: video/mp4
Referer: http://local.xxxx.co.uk/vimeo
Content-Length: 29158540
Origin: http://local.xxxx.co.uk
x-insight: activate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Upload Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Vimeo/1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Range
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range,  X-Requested-With
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2016 08:05:19 GMT
X-Backend-Server: kopiluwak
```

Upload response:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [body] => 
    [status] => 308
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [] => 
            [HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete] => 
            [Server] => Vimeo/1.0
            [Content-Type] => text/plain
            [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => *
            [Timing-Allow-Origin] => *
            [Access-Control-Expose-Headers] => Range
            [Access-Control-Allow-Headers] => Content-Type, Content-Range,  X-Requested-With
            [X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest
            [Access-Control-Allow-Methods] => POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS
            [Content-Length] => 0
            [Connection] => close
            [Range] => bytes=0-29158540
            [Date] => Thu, 14 Apr 2016 08
            [X-Backend-Server] => kopiluwak
        )

)
</pre>
```

CURL DELETE:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [47] => 1
    [10036] => DELETE
    [10015] => 
    [10023] => Array
        (
            [0] => Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json; version=3.2
            [1] => User-Agent: vimeo.php 1.0; (http://developer.vimeo.com/api/docs)
            [2] => Authorization: Bearer xxxx
        )

)
</pre>
```

Response from DELETE:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [error] => Invalid state
        )

    [status] => 500
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Server] => nginx
            [Content-Type] => application/vnd.vimeo.error+json
            [Cache-Control] => no-cache, max-age=315360000
            [Strict-Transport-Security] => max-age=15120000; includeSubDomains; preload
            [Expires] => Sun, 12 Apr 2026 08
            [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
            [Via] => 1.1 varnish
            [Fastly-Debug-Digest] => 771e16bfeec90f734db73b1b0ee67af1dae1f86d0e6c56d4585eb9958a1684b7

            [Content-Length] => 25
            [Date] => Thu, 14 Apr 2016 08
            [Connection] => keep-alive
            [X-Served-By] => cache-iad2138-IAD, cache-lcy1126-LCY
            [X-Cache] => MISS, MISS
            [X-Cache-Hits] => 0, 0
            [X-Timer] => S1460621123.195320,VS0,VE593
            [Vary] => Accept,Vimeo-Client-Id,Accept-Encoding
        )

)
</pre>
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No sorry, even Vimeo are stumped. I'm going to have to find another jQuery upload script or just use plain old browse button :(

Comment: Same problem solved here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/38793105/785819](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38793105/785819) Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just replied to the same issue over on the Vimeo forum, and another SO thread I read - I had the same issue and am simply posting it here as there didn't seem to be a solution on this particular thread.

Also, regarding your post - there's not a lot of information provided in your post.  Your delete request is not all that's required - the assumption would be that you created a valid ticket request, uploaded properly, THEN tried the del request you posted.

Your response is similar to mine below - if your upload script tried to get a ticket AFTER you already got one on your backend, this issue would popup as it did in my code.

**Vimeo post:** 
https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:278394

**My solution:**
I solved my version of the issue - I think Vimeo corrected some stuff on their API recently because my code did not have a bug and then suddenly one appeared recently. I would bet they added rate limiting on their API gateway or potentially overwriting existing requests to clean up old requests...

Anyhow, here is my fix:

In order to complete a video upload via "Resumable HTTP PUT uploads" ([developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos](http://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos)), there are 5 steps.

I do everything but the upload through my PHP backend. I was requesting a ticket through PHP as to not expose some secret info through my modified JS frontend ([github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload](http://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload)) but I had not edited out the ticket request properly through the JS code, so the current bug was probably being triggered on that second invalid request (i.e. overwriting or rate limiting my initial valid request through PHP). Once I bypassed the JS "upload" function properly and jumped right to JS "sendFile_", the upload works properly again.

Hope that helps somebody out there!